# Braintree payments using webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, braintree

Is it possible to use Braintree payments with ASP.NET Web Forms? Braintree provides [an MVC example](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/dotnet/guide/getting_paid).

I tried [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/529110/TransparentplusRedirectpluswithplusBraintreepluswi) but it doesn't work properly. Here is my [server side code](http://wklej.org/id/956419/) and my [template](http://wklej.org/id/956421/); I changed the original version a little bit.

The main problem is that there is no action when the `submit` button is clicked -- the page just reloads. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree.</sub>

I wrote a [simple webforms example](https://gist.github.com/benmills/3678413c4bde46bd0dda) using Transparent Redirect that might help you with your issue.

Looking at your code and what you are describing as the issue, I would guess `SessionUtils.Instance.TransparentRedirectURL` is returning an empty string or `null`, so when you post the form it goes back to the current page.